# Horisontally expand jCarousel Lite carousel slideshow script on the fly

Tags: jquery, jcarousellite

I want to build a carousel slideshow using the jQuery plugin called "jCarousel Lite" (http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/). I have this up and running. The trick is, I want to also build a YouTube-esque "expand" button, which scales this slideshow up to fill the full width of the page.

So far, using jQuery, I’ve managed to build just such an expand button. The problem is, the “next” and “previous” buttons still only slide the distance that was defined when the carousel was first initialized. Obviously, these need to slide a longer distance, now that the width is wider.

So essentially what I need is information as to how I can change the distance the “next” and “previous” buttons slide, after the carousel has first been initialized.

Answer (score 1):

So, I may have found a semi-solution to my "expand" problem.

Reinitializing the slideshow didn't work. I couldn't find (or hook in to) the variable that defines how far each slide travels on each next/prev click.

So my solution was to embed the slideshow at its expanded size, but with smaller images inside. On clicking my expand button, I didn't expand the slideshow itself, only the items inside. Combine this with a containing div which was set to the small width and overflow: hidden, things worked almost perfectly.